# Get License from Payload Id

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.6, burn

Is there a way to get the License file from the Payload in custom BootstrapperApplication. It appears that the Engine has Version and String variables, but no way to see what is in the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your payload files will be extracted to  `Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);` you can pick your license file from this location.